# Count number of orders over date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this: orders(id, created_ts, status)
I want to generate a MySQL query which shows the number of open orders with created_ts.
created_ts is MySQL timestamp

Sample data:

```
id  created_ts status
--- ---------- -------
1   11-1-2017  Open
2   11-1-2017  Open
3   12-1-2017  Open
4   13-1-2017  Open
5   13-1-2017  Closed
6   14-1-2017  Closed
```

Outpur:

```
created_ts  count  
--------    ------  
11-1-2017   2  
12-1-2017   3  
13-1-2017   4  
14-1-2017   4
```

Where count is the number of orders opened for that date.
It is calculated as follows.
count of orders for a date = all orders with status = 'Open' with created_ts <= created_ts of that row.

I don't know how to approach the problem. 
could anyone please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by `created_ts <= created_ts` ?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo I meant all orders with status = 'Open' which are created previously to the current processing row.

Comment: Then, GROUP BY date(created_ts) will output the result.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo No. Because the created date will not be the same. I updated the question with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need cumulative sum:

```
SELECT t.created_ts,
         (@running_total := @running_total + count(case when status='Open'then t.id else null end)) AS countval
    FROM TABLE t
    JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
group by t.created_ts
ORDER BY t.created_ts
```

Comment: This query won't return the results as I mentioned in the question. The created_ts can be different and it should not be grouped.

Comment: can you please give some table structure in your question

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 2):

You could use a correlated query to get running total of opened orders for distinct dates

```
select t1.created_ts,
  (select count(*)
   from demo 
   where created_ts <=t1.created_ts 
   and status = 'Open') date_wise_sum
from (
  select distinct created_ts
  from demo 
) t1
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KERLI37161)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, we look at open records only and ignore the closed records. You want a running total, which you get with a windows function, available as of MySQL 8:

```
select created_ts, sum(sum(status = 'Open')) over (order by created_ts) as cnt
from mytable
group by created_ts
order by created_ts;
```

In earlier versions you can for instance join the counts to the dates:

```
select dates.created_ts, sum(counted.cnt) as total
from
(
  select distinct created_ts 
  from mytable 
) dates
join 
(
  select created_ts, count(*) as cnt
  from mytable
  where status = 'Open'
  group by created_ts
) counted on counted.created_ts <= dates.created_ts
group by dates.created_ts
order by dates.created_ts;
```